# Update Multiple Labels in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

`@interface ViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray * gameB;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray * rows;
    - (IBAction)initialize:(id)sender;
    - (BOOL) isEmpty;
    @end`

```
- (IBAction)startGme:(id)sender {
    _rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    _gameB = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects :_rows , _rows ,_rows ,nil];
}
```

`

[This is how my storyboard would look. These all values update from a 2-D array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LWL3.png)I am new to objective c. What I am trying to do is update a few labels every time a change in my array happens.
I know how to update one label. But if the number of labels is more than one is there a generic way to do that so everytime values in my array changes, my labels get the update or I need to update each label hard code?
Any reference code would be helpful.

Comment: Are the UILabel on the same screen? I mean are they subview of same parent?

Comment: Please show what you have tried (code),

Comment: Along with what @shallowThought Said, also add screen shot of the page fro better under understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the array and set the label.

```
[yourArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id x, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
   UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:index];
   NSString *str = (NSString*)x;
   [label setText:x];
}];
```

This assumes your labels has tag set 0-(num of labels), and that your array contains NSString.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an outlet collection that is gonna look like that in swift:

```
    @IBOutlet var labelCollection: [UILabel]!
```

Then you have to link labels you want to update simultaneously to this declared collection in storyboard. Iterate over this collection and update all of it's contents like you want.